# Installing entity framework in asp.net core osx

Tags: macos, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using Visual Studio Code on OSX. I am starting to learn asp.net core and so far I'm only able to find tutorials that teach edit `project.json` to add Entity Framework dependency & then run `dotnet restore` command but I'm not using yeoman to generate asp.net core project. I used `dotnet new -t web` to generate project which doesn't contain any `project.json`. How can use Entity Framework to store data in database?

Also please suggest some latest resources for osx users. All the existing resource on MS website are for Visual Studio Windows.

Answer (score 1):

so I figured out. I have had to add like in case of `Project.json` we had dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
```

We can write these as follow in `*/ProjectName.csproj` file

Say if you want to add EntityFrameworkCore than all we need to do is:

```
<ItemGroup>
   ..
   ..
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and then after saving the file .csproj. Run command `dotnet restore`